# Ordering Dynamics CRM Workflow Interface Custom Workflow Activities

Tags: guid, dynamics-crm-2013, workflow-activity

We have developed many custom workflow activities for Dynamics CRM 2013 SP1. We now have over 100 different custom workflow activities. The workflow interface seems to order these by the PluginTypeID field from the PluginType entity. I found this out by doing the following querying
`SELECT 
   Name,
   PluginTypeID
FROM dbo.PluginTypeBase
ORDER BY PluginTypeID`

My question is does anyone know how I could order this list so that it is sorts by name alphabetically? Overtime, the searching through this list of illogically sorted workflow activities wastes time. I am open to supported and unsupported customizations for this.

Original thoughts are to edit the guids to be sequential in the database by the name but this is very risky and have not tested if this can be done with various constraints/foreign key relationships likely to exist.

Comment: What do you mean, the Process Overview in Menue "Settings -> Processes" ?

Comment: I tried to post an image but I do not have enough reputation to do so. What I mean is when you are editing a workflow in the interface, when you click "Add Step", any of the custom workflow activities created that are listed below the out of the box workflow activities. These are sorted by a GUID and not sorted alphabetically, which makes it very frustrating for someone to find a step.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean, hopefully this link works. http://i.stack.imgur.com/7AQNJ.png